# closing windowA which opened windowB from window B in powerbuilder 11.5

Tags: powerbuilder

Suppose I have windowA, windowB and windowC and many other.

I want to close a window which opened another window from the opened window.

like How do I close windowA from windowB If windowB is opened from windowA?

Any window may open any other window and they have the same menu item.

All windows are of main type.

Comment: What is a difference between A-B case and B-C case? I don't see it.

Comment: Is the window B a response window?

Comment: I just want to close a window which opened another window from the opened window NiematojakTomasz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no way to find out how a particular window was opened, you'll have to pass the reference to the new window and store it there for later use.

On window A, use `OpenWithParm(windowB,this)` (where this refers to Window A), and on WindowB in the open event: `iw_opener = Message.PowerObjectParm`. Of course some sanity checking should be done here, and iw_opener has to be declared as an instance variable as `window iw_openener`.

To close WindowA from WindowB just do `close(iw_opener)`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what **kind** of windows your windows are the answer is 'it depends'.

If they are all main type windows you do something like:

`IF IsValid(w_a) THEN
  Close(w_a)
END IF`

This calls the close function on window 'w_a'.  There may be code in the closequery event which will prevent it from closing however.